# Spark Jaccard similarity computation by min hashing slow compared to trivial approach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Given 2 huge list of values, I am trying to compute [jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between them in Spark using Scala.

Assume `colHashed1` contains the first list of values and `colHashed2` contains the second list.

**Approach 1(trivial approach):**

```
val jSimilarity = colHashed1.intersection(colHashed2).distinct.count/(colHashed1.union(colHashed2).distinct.count.toDouble)
```

**Approach 2(using minHashing):**

I have used the approach explained [here](https://github.com/chrisjmccormick/MinHash/blob/master/runMinHashExample.py).

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32

def getCRC32 (s : String) : Int =
{
    val crc=new CRC32
    crc.update(s.getBytes)
    return crc.getValue.toInt & 0xffffffff
}

val maxShingleID = Math.pow(2,32)-1
def pickRandomCoeffs(kIn : Int) : Array[Int] =
{
  var k = kIn
  val randList = Array.fill(k){0}

  while(k > 0)
  {
    // Get a random shingle ID.

    var randIndex = (Math.random()*maxShingleID).toInt

    // Ensure that each random number is unique.
    while(randList.contains(randIndex))
    {
      randIndex = (Math.random()*maxShingleID).toInt
    }

    // Add the random number to the list.
    k = k - 1
    randList(k) = randIndex
   } 

   return randList
}

val colHashed1 = list1Values.map(a => getCRC32(a))
val colHashed2 = list2Values.map(a => getCRC32(a))

val nextPrime = 4294967311L
val numHashes = 10

val coeffA = pickRandomCoeffs(numHashes)
val coeffB = pickRandomCoeffs(numHashes)

var signature1 = Array.fill(numHashes){0}
for (i <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
    // Evaluate the hash function.
    val hashCodeRDD = colHashed1.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))

    // Track the lowest hash code seen.
    signature1(i) = hashCodeRDD.min.toInt
}

var signature2 = Array.fill(numHashes){0}
for (i <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
    // Evaluate the hash function.
    val hashCodeRDD = colHashed2.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))

    // Track the lowest hash code seen.
    signature2(i) = hashCodeRDD.min.toInt
}


var count = 0
// Count the number of positions in the minhash signature which are equal.
for(k <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
  if(signature1(k) == signature2(k))
    count = count + 1
}  
val jSimilarity = count/numHashes.toDouble
```

*Approach 1 seems to outperform Approach 2 in terms of time always*. When I analyzed the code, `min()` function call on the `RDD` in Approach 2 takes significant time and that function is called many times depending upon how many hash functions are used.

The intersection and union operations used in Approach 1 seems to work faster compared to the repeated min() function calls.

I don't understand why minHashing does not help here. I expected minHashing to work faster compared to trivial approach. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Sample data can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/Mj7mF8vd)

Comment: Can you add sample data for your col1 and col2 in the dataset ?

Comment: @tuxdna sample data link added at the end of the question

Answer (score 0):

JaccardSimilarity with MinHash is not giving consistent results:

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32

object Jaccard {
  def getCRC32(s: String): Int = {
    val crc = new CRC32
    crc.update(s.getBytes)
    return crc.getValue.toInt & 0xffffffff
  }

  def pickRandomCoeffs(kIn: Int, maxShingleID: Double): Array[Int] = {
    var k = kIn
    val randList = Array.ofDim[Int](k)

    while (k > 0) {
      // Get a random shingle ID.
      var randIndex = (Math.random() * maxShingleID).toInt
      // Ensure that each random number is unique.
      while (randList.contains(randIndex)) {
        randIndex = (Math.random() * maxShingleID).toInt
      }
      // Add the random number to the list.
      k = k - 1
      randList(k) = randIndex
    }
    return randList
  }


  def approach2(list1Values: List[String], list2Values: List[String]) = {

    val maxShingleID = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1

    val colHashed1 = list1Values.map(a => getCRC32(a))
    val colHashed2 = list2Values.map(a => getCRC32(a))

    val nextPrime = 4294967311L
    val numHashes = 10

    val coeffA = pickRandomCoeffs(numHashes, maxShingleID)
    val coeffB = pickRandomCoeffs(numHashes, maxShingleID)

    val signature1 = for (i <- 0 until numHashes) yield {
      val hashCodeRDD = colHashed1.map(ele => (coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime)
      hashCodeRDD.min.toInt // Track the lowest hash code seen.
    }

    val signature2 = for (i <- 0 until numHashes) yield {
      val hashCodeRDD = colHashed2.map(ele => (coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime)
      hashCodeRDD.min.toInt // Track the lowest hash code seen
    }

    val count = (0 until numHashes)
      .map(k => if (signature1(k) == signature2(k)) 1 else 0)
      .fold(0)(_ + _)


    val jSimilarity = count / numHashes.toDouble
    jSimilarity
  }


  //  def approach1(list1Values: List[String], list2Values: List[String]) = {
  //    val colHashed1 = list1Values.toSet
  //    val colHashed2 = list2Values.toSet
  //
  //    val jSimilarity = colHashed1.intersection(colHashed2).distinct.count / (colHashed1.union(colHashed2).distinct.count.toDouble)
  //    jSimilarity
  //  }


  def approach1(list1Values: List[String], list2Values: List[String]) = {
    val colHashed1 = list1Values.toSet
    val colHashed2 = list2Values.toSet

    val jSimilarity = (colHashed1 & colHashed2).size / (colHashed1 ++ colHashed2).size.toDouble
    jSimilarity
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val list1Values = List("a", "b", "c")
    val list2Values = List("a", "b", "d")

    for (i <- 0 until 5) {
      println(s"Iteration ${i}")
      println(s" - Approach 1: ${approach1(list1Values, list2Values)}")
      println(s" - Approach 2: ${approach2(list1Values, list2Values)}")
    }

  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Iteration 0
 - Approach 1: 0.5
 - Approach 2: 0.5
Iteration 1
 - Approach 1: 0.5
 - Approach 2: 0.5
Iteration 2
 - Approach 1: 0.5
 - Approach 2: 0.8
Iteration 3
 - Approach 1: 0.5
 - Approach 2: 0.8
Iteration 4
 - Approach 1: 0.5
 - Approach 2: 0.4
```

Why are you using it?

Comment: Approach 1 gives exact value of jaccard similarity. Approach 2 is an approximation. Approach 2 is expected to be much simpler for computation than Approach 1. If we tune 'numHashes' value in approach 2, we can get the approximation closer to actual jaccard similarity given by approach 1 i think. The issue is approximation seems to be computationally intensive than exact

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the overhead cost for minHashing approach just outweighs its functionality in Spark. Especially as `numHashes` increases.
Here are some observations I've found in your code:

First, `while (randList.contains(randIndex))` this part will surely slow down your process as numHashes (which is by the way equal to the size of randList) increases.

Second, You can save some time if you rewrite this code:

```
var signature1 = Array.fill(numHashes){0}
for (i <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
    // Evaluate the hash function.
    val hashCodeRDD = colHashed1.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))

    // Track the lowest hash code seen.
    signature1(i) = hashCodeRDD.min.toInt
}

var signature2 = Array.fill(numHashes){0}
for (i <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
    // Evaluate the hash function.
    val hashCodeRDD = colHashed2.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))

    // Track the lowest hash code seen.
    signature2(i) = hashCodeRDD.min.toInt
}


var count = 0
// Count the number of positions in the minhash signature which are equal.
for(k <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
  if(signature1(k) == signature2(k))
    count = count + 1
}
```

into

```
var count = 0
for (i <- 0 to numHashes - 1)
{
    val hashCodeRDD1 = colHashed1.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))
    val hashCodeRDD2 = colHashed2.map(ele => ((coeffA(i) * ele + coeffB(i)) % nextPrime))

    val sig1 = hashCodeRDD1.min.toInt
    val sig2 = hashCodeRDD2.min.toInt

    if (sig1 == sig2) { count = count + 1 }
}
```

This method simplifies the three loops into one. However, I am not sure if that would give a huge boost in computational time.

One other suggestion I have, assuming that the first approach still turns out to be much faster is to use the property of sets to modify the first approach:

```
val colHashed1_dist = colHashed1.distinct
val colHashed2_dist = colHashed2.distinct
val intersect_cnt = colHashed1_dist.intersection(colHashed2_dist).distinct.count

val jSimilarity = intersect_cnt/(colHashed1_dist.count + colHashed2_dist.count - intersect_cnt).toDouble
```

with that, instead of getting the union, you can just reuse the value of the intersection.

Comment: I agree with your points. But as you said the changes in code organization did not have any significant impact. I am still wondering whether there is any better minHash implementation in spark

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in LSH apporach you would calculate minHash only once for each of your documents and then compare two minHases for each possible pair of documents. And in case of trivial approach you would perform full comparison of documents for each possible pair of documents. Which is roughly N^2/2 number of comparisons. Hence extra cost of calculating minHashes is negligible for large enough number of documents.

You should  actually compare the performance of the trivial approach:

```
val jSimilarity = colHashed1.intersection(colHashed2).distinct.count/(colHashed1.union(colHashed2).distinct.count.toDouble)
```

and performance of the Jaccard distance calculation (last lines in your code):

```
var count = 0
// Count the number of positions in the minhash signature which are equal.
for(k <- 0 to numHashes-1)
{
  if(signature1(k) == signature2(k))
    count = count + 1
}  
val jSimilarity = count/numHashes.toDouble
```